# Can we have a more specific anchor text for some of the comment magic-links?

Tags: feature-request, comments, wording, magic-links

(Also asked 6+ years ago [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261301/make-help-center-magic-link-anchor-text-more-unique-and-descriptive?noredirect=1&lq=1)),

There are a couple of ways to write help-center links with short sentences, like `[help/on-topic]`.  These are useful when writing help comments to new users (for those who don't have @Glorfindel's Lost Soul script).  But the anchor text simply says "Help center":

[image]

Even if the link is the `[help/behavior]` shortcut, it says "help center", which can be confusing and annoying.  Can we have them show the name of the page when you link to them, e.g. "How to ask" (which *does* work for `[ask]`)?